# Is sendmail configuration question appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question about why I had to solve a particular sendmail -  /var/spool/mqueue problem the way I did. Is that an appropriate question for Unix & Linux?

Specifically, CentOS 6 installed sendmail a particular way, and I wound up having to modify /var/spool/mqueue permissions as well as modifying mail's group entry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic; it clearly fits under

- Using or administering a *nix desktop or server

and

- Applications packaged in *nix distributions (note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)

This also might be appropriate on the sysadmin-focused site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). But it's on-topic here too.

Comment: Addendum: don't cross-post, by the way. Pick the site which seems best.